# why 2TB external HDD is recognized as 800 GB only in Ubuntu 8.10

Tags: ubuntu, partition, fdisk, external-hdd

I had a **2 TB** external HDD which I formatted as below.

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
```

After issuing the above command, I did the following steps.

- Then selected option <kbd>p</kbd>. (To print the partition table).
- Then selected option <kbd>n</kbd>. (To add a new partition).
- Then selected <kbd>1</kbd>. (This option I selected by default).
- Then finally selected option <kbd>w</kbd>. (To write back the changes to
  disk).

After formatting the external hard drive using the above steps, I did the below command.

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1
```

Now, everything seemed fine and I had a external hard disk available in my RHEL6 system. It was mounted automatically without any issues.

Now, I connected this hard disk to Ubuntu 8.10 system. The external HDD was not recognized. I had to repeat the above steps again and finally when the hard disk was recognized it had only **800 GB** available out of the **2 TB** space.

**EDIT**

The Ubuntu 8.10 system also has the file system type as ext3. I ran the below command to identify that.

```
ramesh@server2:/$ df -hT
Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2     ext3    184G   20G  155G  12% /
```

Why is it so? Is it because of some partition table issues? I am not pretty clear of these concepts.

Comment: Ubuntu 8.10 is ancient, maybe it has problems with larger HDs.

Comment: What do you get out of `gdisk /dev/sdb`? Also, please provide an `lsblk` output - and, last, why ubuntu 2008? Its lts lifespan ended a coupla years ago, I think...

Comment: Ahh, well, that foils my plans. Sorry, @Ramesh.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel only allows for certain amount of HDD, the same goes for RAM.  An odd concept for Hardware caps, but nonetheless, 8.1 had an actual cap of 800 GB for space because at the time, the thought of going past 1TB was ridiculous and silly.  That and 1TB Drives weren't around I believe.