# can I use 2 mount points for 2 partitions from external HDD?

Tags: mount, external-hdd

I have a **2 TB** external HDD which I connect to the Ubuntu 8.10 system. However, after connecting the external HDD, I created just a single partition and because of that I could use only **750 GB** out of the available **2 TB**. I had posted a question earlier regarding the same over [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134905/why-2tb-external-hdd-is-recognized-as-800-gb-only-in-ubuntu-8-10).

Now, I realized I could just create 2 primary partitions each with **1 TB** in size and apparently each primary partition would be recognized as **750 GB** each and thus making the total avaialble space as **1.5 TB**.

Now, my question is, can I use 2 mount points for the 2 primary partitions available from the external hard disk at the same time? Something like below.

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /media/backup1
mount /dev/sdc2 /media/backup2
```

Comment: Yes, that should work. Did you try it?

Comment: @Kevin, not yet. I have started to make a new file system in the second partition. Before mounting it, I needed to clarify myself :)

Comment: Well, if you're only getting 750GB, I'd make three... This of course assumes that its ext3 that's limiting the size, not something else (e.g., if the kernel thinks the disk is only 750GB, then additional partitions aren't going to help.)

Comment: @mikeserv, I am also thinking in your line only. But am still not pretty clear on the MBR vs GPT concept for partition tables.

Comment: See [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/booting.html). And pretty much any other page at that site is likely to help. Rod Smith is awesome-sauce.

Comment: Oh wait - is this still ubuntu 8.04 or something?

Comment: @mikeserv, yeah, it is the same ubuntu 8.04 only.

Comment: Ahh, then, yes, you need to do multiple mount points and it will work as you've described. I'm sorry for wasting your time again. But if you have authority enough to create new mountpoints and map them - maybe you could upgrade instead?

Comment: @mikeserv, for upgrading to the newer OS only, I am trying to maximize the external HDD capacity so that I could backup more data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We can use 2 mount points for 2 different partitions from the same external HDD as below. It works.

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /media/backup1
mount /dev/sdc2 /media/backup2
```